# Access Undisposed Resource of a Disposable Object Outside of Using Block

Tags: c#, using-statement

The code below is perfectly legal.

```
DisposableObject disposableObject;
...
using (disposableObject = new DisposableObject(...))
{
     disposableObject.UseDisposableResource();
}
...
var result = disposableObject.AccessUndisposedResource();
```

**Q** Make use of it or stay clear?

Comment: Generally I would shy away from `using` statements that don't introduce a variable, like `using (var disposableObject = new DisposableObject())`. So no, I would not make use of this. There are of course, always exceptions depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Does your `DisposableObject` class promise that `AccessUndisposedResource()` will continue working after `Dispose()` has been called?

Comment: @participant Not "of course". It's common for classes to simply document that the class must not be used after `Dispose()` has been called, and that attempts to use it anyway *may* fail with `ObjectDisposedException`. If you then use it in a way that happens not to currently cause an exception, but which still isn't supported by the documentation, then it's entirely possible that an update to a newer version of `DisposableObject` would expose flaws in your code. That's why I asked not whether it works, but whether it's documented to work. But if you say "yes", if it is documented, that's good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of norms / expectations involved here:

1. A disposed object is considered generally finished with and is assumed *unusable* after disposal (although not compiler-enforced)
2. `using` variables are usually declared within the using statement, which exlicitly prevents usage when they have been disposed (again, not compiler-enforced)

Your code violates both these norms - you have a disposed object which is still expected to be usable, as well as a using block which disposes an external variable which remains in scope after the block. The result? Confusion and hard-to-read-and-maintain code.

So yes, steer well clear.

Answer (score 3):

I would absolutely steer clear of that. The usual convention is to introduce the variable in the scope of the using statement only, so doing otherwise is asking for developer confusion and hard to find bugs.

If developers expect this, by convention:

```
using (DisposableObject disposableObject = new DisposableObject())
{
    ...
}
```

Then breaking convention will lead odd looking code at best, and strange behaviour/bugs at worst.

The typical usage of the `using` statement, in my experience, is very similar in *developer* expectation to the following (even though it is a scope change, not a nulling of an object):

```
DisposableObject disposableObject = new DisposableObject();

...
disposableObject.Dispose();
disposableObject = null;
```

If a developer under my care ever did such a thing, I would tell them to cease and desist! I would also change all instances I found of it, since it has such a code smell and so much potential for causing hard to find/understand bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I would not make use of it, as anyone reading your code will think the usage of `disposableObject` after the `using` is of a *usable object*.

I would keep the scope of the disposable object within the confines of the `using` block as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the usage of `using`-block is a bit misleading. I'd personally use the `disposableObject` only inside the block, and split the `AccessUndisposedResource()`-logics to some other object.

**Maybe something like this:**

```
ResultType result = null;
using (DisposableObject disposableObject = new DisposableObject(...))
{
   disposableObject.UseDisposableResource();
   ...
   result = disposableObject.AccessUndisposedResource();
}
...
// Now we can access the undisposed resource here with 'result'-variable
```